# How to get turtles to move to the target?

Tags: netlogo

I'm stumped with an issue in my model. I have a model that looks to simulate an office environment, where there are two breeds: `employees` and `citizens`. The `employees` stay in the office, denoted by grey coloured patches, and the `citizens`stay in the outside world denoted by black colour patches.

In the middle of the world `patch 0 0`  there is an office, where employees go to pick up money. There are 4 `service-desks` where both `employees` and `citizens` are to meet for a transfer of money to occur. Here is the full code:

```
globals [ office-space ]

breed [ offices office ]
breed [ service-desks service-desk ]
breed [ employees employee ]
breed [ citizens citizen ]


offices-own [ money ]
employees-own [ money-held ]
citizens-own [ money-received ]

to setup
  clear-all

  create-offices 1
  ask offices  [
    set shape "building institution"
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    set money num-of-money ]


  create-employees num-of-employees
  ask employees [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]

  create-citizens num-of-citizens
  ask citizens [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor  ]

  ;; create four service desks

  ask patch 0 8 [
    sprout 1 [
      set breed service-desks
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 ]
  ]

    ask patch 0 -8 [
    sprout 1 [
      set breed service-desks
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 ]
  ]

    ask patch -8 0 [
    sprout 1 [
      set breed service-desks
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 ]
  ]

    ask patch 8 0 [
    sprout 1 [
      set breed service-desks
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 ]
  ]

;; create office space

set office-space patches with [ pxcor <= 8 and pxcor >= -8 and pycor <= 8 and pycor >= -8 ]
ask office-space [ set pcolor grey]


place-on-color-employees ;; sets all employees randomly within the grey square

place-on-color-citizens ;; sets citizens randomly outside of the grey box

  reset-ticks

end

to place-on-color-employees
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = grey])
  ask employees [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end

to place-on-color-citizens
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = black])
  ask citizens [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end

to go

  employee-movement
  employee-take-money
  citizen-movement
 

 tick
end


to employee-movement

  ask employees [
   ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black

    [ rt random-float 360]
    [ forward 1 ]
    
   let target one-of citizens
    
   if money-held > 0 [
     set heading (towards target)
    ]
  ]

end


to citizen-movement
  ;; citizens walk only in the black patches, they do not go into the office area
  ask citizens [
   ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = grey

    [ rt random-float 360]
    [ forward 1 ]

   ;; if they have no money, then the citizens will walk to one of the service-desks
   let target one-of service-desks

    if money-received = 0 [
      set heading (towards target )
  ]
  ]

end

to employee-take-money ;; asks employees to go to the main office and get money

  ask employees [
    if any? turtles-here with [ shape = "building institution" and color = yellow] [
      set money-held money-held + 1
      set color green ]
    ]

end
```

The issue I have is that within the `employee-movement` function, the `employees` will not move towards their targets. Whereas, the `citizens` will move to their targets. The code for both breeds is basically the same. The `employees` tend to congregate around the central patch, rather than moving to the targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited after receiving the full code:

The problem lies with how you define target as a local variable (`let target one-of service-desks`) each time you call the code. However, since there is more than one `service-desk`, nothing is forcing them to choose the same `service-desk` each time. This means that the `employees`, who are standing in the middle of the four `service-desks`, are basically taking a step in a random direction at each tick. The `citizens` on the other hand stand outside of the square on which the `service-desks` are located. Because of that, all of the `service-desks` are roughly in the same direction for them, so their general movement also goes in that direction.

I see two different options for working around this. The first one is to not use `let target one-of service-desks` but use `let target min-one-of service-desks [distance myself]`. This moves them to the closest `service-desk` rather than to a random service desk.

The other option would be to set target as a `turtles-own` variable, and not letting them choose a new one all the time.

Finally I streamlined your setup a little bit, reducing the amount of code you needed.

```
globals [ 
  
  office-space
  
  num-of-money
  num-of-employees
  num-of-citizens
]

breed [ offices office ]
breed [ service-desks service-desk ]
breed [ employees employee ]
breed [ citizens citizen ]

offices-own [ money ]
employees-own [ money-held ]
citizens-own [ money-received ]

to setup
  clear-all

  set num-of-money 100
  set num-of-employees 5
  set num-of-citizens 5
  

  create-offices 1 [
    set shape "building institution"
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    set money num-of-money 
  ]


  create-employees num-of-employees [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
  ]
  
  create-citizens num-of-citizens [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.5
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor  
  ]
  
  ;; create four service desks
  
  let service-desk-patches (patch-set patch 0 8 patch 8 0 patch 0 -8 patch -8 0)
  
  ask service-desk-patches [
    sprout-service-desks 1 [
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 
    ]
  ]
  
  
  ;; create office space
  
  set office-space patches with [ pxcor <= 8 and pxcor >= -8 and pycor <= 8 and pycor >= -8 ]
  ask office-space [ set pcolor grey]
  
  
  place-on-color-employees ;; sets all employees randomly within the grey square
  
  place-on-color-citizens ;; sets citizens randomly outside of the grey box
  
  reset-ticks
  
end

to place-on-color-employees
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = grey])
  ask employees [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end

to place-on-color-citizens
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = black])
  ask citizens [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end

to go

  employee-movement
  employee-take-money
  citizen-movement
 

 tick
end


to employee-movement
  
  ask employees [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black
    
    [ rt random-float 360]
    [ forward 1 ]
    
    let target min-one-of citizens [distance myself]
    
    if money-held > 0 [
      set heading (towards target)
    ]
  ]
  
end


to citizen-movement
  ;; citizens walk only in the black patches, they do not go into the office area
  ask citizens [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = grey
    
    [ rt random-float 360]
    [ forward 1 ]
    
    ;; if they have no money, then the citizens will walk to one of the service-desks
    let target min-one-of service-desks [distance myself]
    
    if money-received = 0 [
      set heading (towards target )
    ]
  ]
  
end

to employee-take-money ;; asks employees to go to the main office and get money
  
  ask employees [
    if any? offices-here [
      set money-held money-held + 1
      set color green ]
  ]
  
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I guess I just don't understand why the `citizens` breed would go to the target, where the `employee` breed does not. The targets for both breeds is the same. As well, there are 4 targets, and it doesn't matter which target an agent goes to.

Comment: I've also adjusted the target to be one of `citizens` because at least they are going to the specific target, and still the `employees` tend to just congregate around `patch 0 0`

Comment: @premiumcopypaper That's why I mentioned  the `pcolor` that they are avoiding. That one differs between employees and citizens. But again, I can't be sure without seeing the full code

Comment: A minimal reproducible example of code makes it a lot easier to advise: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, I've dropped the entire code. I'm a beginner at this so it will likely be clunky, but I am just trying to learn how to build models

Comment: @premiumcopypaper After reading the entire code, the problem is indeed with your target, with the solution being the suggestion I gave before. I will edit the answer to reflect it